# Eclipse logcat regex show only tags ending in .java

Tags: android, regex, eclipse

For example if I have these tags:

- ClassA.java
- ClassB.java
- ClassC

I want the eclipse logcat only shows messages with tags ending in ".java":

- ClassA.java
- ClassB.java

Can this be possible with logcat regex?

Comment: `ending in ".java"` = `\.java$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex(escape `\` if you need to):

```
.*\.java$
```

This means anything that ends with `.java`

Comment: To complete this answer, he might also have to add a `tag=` statement in front of the regex.

Comment: Thanks! my understanding over `logcat` is very poor.